# SQL Server 2008 to 2014 RAISERROR migration script

Tags: sql-server-2008, syntax, migration, sql-server-2014, raiserror

Between SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2008 there is an issue with `RAISERROR` syntax.

Are there any scripts for `RAISERROR` syntax migration to SQL Server 2014, or database tool to migrate SQL Server 2008 to 2014?

Best regards

Comment: I believe that Raiserror is being replaced by Throw...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manub22/archive/2013/12/31/new-throw-statement-in-sql-server-2012-vs-raiserror.aspx  & http://sqlhints.com/tag/raiserror-vs-throw/

Answer (score 1):

Both `RAISERROR` and `THROW` statements are used to raise an error in Sql Server.

The journey of `RAISERROR` started from Sql Server 7.0, where as the journey of `THROW` statement has just began with Sql Server 2012. Obviously, Microsoft has suggesting we start using `THROW` statement instead of `RAISERROR`. `THROW` statements seem to be simple and easier to use than `RAISERROR`. `RAISERROR` can’t be used in the Sql Server 2014′s natively compiled `Stored Procedures`.